# PHP - XML Object inside XML Object in Soap Response

Tags: php, xml, soap

```xml
<diffgr:diffgram
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet
        xmlns="">
        <MultiplePrices diffgr:id="MultiplePrices1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <stationID>06</stationID>
            <station>Aeroporto Ponta Delgada</station>
            <weekDayOpen>00:00</weekDayOpen>
            <weekDayClose>00:00</weekDayClose>
            <supplier_Code>0</supplier_Code>
            <groupID>B</groupID>
            <group_Name>GRUPO B</group_Name>
            <extrasIncluded>CDW</extrasIncluded>
            <extrasRequired/>
            <extrasAccepted/>
            <extrasAvailable>ADD,BSEAT,BOST,CSEAT,PAI,SCDW,THW</extrasAvailable>
            <package/>
            <dayValueWithDiscount>56.03</dayValueWithDiscount>
            <prepaidRate>false</prepaidRate>
            <allExtras>
                <xs:schema
                    xmlns=""
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
                    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="AllExtras" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="AllExtras">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="groupID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="extraID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="extra" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="taxRate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="valueWithoutRounding" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="extra_Included" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="extra_Required" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            <xs:element name="extra_Accepted" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram
                    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                    <DocumentElement>
                        <AllExtras diffgr:id="AllExtras1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                            <groupID>B</groupID>
                            <extraID>ADD</extraID>
                            <extra>ADD</extra>
                            <description>Condutor Adicional</description>
                            <value>4.31</value>
                            <taxRate>16.00</taxRate>
                            <valueWithoutRounding>4.31034</valueWithoutRounding>
                            <extra_Included>false</extra_Included>
                            <extra_Required>false</extra_Required>
                            <extra_Accepted>false</extra_Accepted>
                            <accept_quantity>true</accept_quantity>
                            <insurance>false</insurance>
                            <excess>0</excess>
                            <extraByDay>true</extraByDay>
                        </AllExtras>
                        <AllExtras diffgr:id="AllExtras2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                            <groupID>B</groupID>
                            <extraID>BSEAT</extraID>
                            <extra/>
                            <description>Cadeira de bebé</description>
                            <value>3.64</value>
                            <taxRate>16.00</taxRate>
                            <valueWithoutRounding>3.63923</valueWithoutRounding>
                            <extra_Included>false</extra_Included>
                            <extra_Required>false</extra_Required>
                            <extra_Accepted>false</extra_Accepted>
                            <accept_quantity>true</accept_quantity>
                            <insurance>false</insurance>
                            <excess>0</excess>
                            <extraByDay>true</extraByDay>
                        </AllExtras>
                    </DocumentElement>
                </diffgr:diffgram>
            </allExtras>
        </MultiplePrices>
    </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

```php
<?php
$xml = $api->MultiplePricesResult->getMultiplePrices->any;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$groupID = $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->groupID;
$group_name = $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->group_Name;
$group_total_value = $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->previewValue;
$group_daily_value = $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->totalDayValueWithTax;
$group_image_url = $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->imageURL;
$pickUprentalStation = $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->station;
$nrDays = $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->nrDays;
```

Having the above Soap response below, I cannot access or loop through the all Extras element, it always show as empty, any idea how can i access or loop through that element ? When printing $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->package or even allExtras I got nothing. Can someone help and let me know how to access that part ?

This is the result of the XML

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [NewDataSet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [MultiplePrices] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [stationID] => 06
                    [station] => Aeroporto Ponta Delgada
                    [weekDayOpen] => 00:00
                    [weekDayClose] => 00:00
                    [supplier_Code] => 0
                    [groupID] => B
                    [group_Name] => GRUPO B
                    [SIPP] => EDMR
                    [imageURL] => https://i.postimg.cc/PNsKy0Y0/FIAT-PANDA-CROSS-FRENTE.png
                    [rateCode] => 10
                    [dynamicRate] => false
                    [nrDays] => 13
                    [dayValue] => 56.03
                    [totalDayValueWithTax] => 65.00
                    [kmsValue] => 0.00
                    [kmsIncluded] => true
                    [kmsFreePerDay] => 0
                    [previewValue] => 845.00
                    [valueWithotTax] => 728.45
                    [taxRate] => 16.00
                    [otherTaxValue] => 0.00
                    [taxValue] => 116.55
                    [extrasIncluded] => CDW
                    [extrasRequired] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [extrasAccepted] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [extrasAvailable] => ADD,BSEAT,BOST,CSEAT,PAI,SCDW,THW
                    [package] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [dayValueWithDiscount] => 56.03
                    [previewValueWithDiscount] => 845.00
                    [valueWithDiscountWithoutTax] => 728.45
                    [percentualDiscount] => 0.00
                    [prepaidRate] => false
                    [allExtras] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But if i try to access $xml->NewDataSet->MultiplePrices->package it's empty: SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) and my question is how to access or loop through the information in allExtras.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your exact expected output?

Comment: What does `$xml` contain after the first line of PHP code? Where are you attempting to do any kind of loop? What is the meaning of the XML document you've included in the question?

Comment: `<package/>` it's an empty element and `allExtras` looks like an XSD embedded in the document. They have no text values.

Comment: This are calls from Soap API requests, but I can't seem to access that specific allExtras tree information it's not like other Objects or i'm not accessing it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out i can easily access all elements in an easier way including the ondes in deeper levels with xpath, so this was what i was searching for.

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//AllExtras') as $item_extra)
```

and can even filter further like.

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//AllExtras[groupID = "B"]') as $item_extra)
```

Comment: I forgot to say that base worked like a charm for everything.